# C Macro for minimum of two numbers

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, minimum

I want to make a simple macro with #define for returning the smaller of two numbers.

How can i do this in C ? Suggest some ideas, and see if you can make it more obfuscated too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MIN and MAX in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437404/min-and-max-in-c)

Answer (score -6, accepted):

For slightly obfuscated, try this:

```
#define MIN(a,b)  ((((a)-(b))&0x80000000) >> 31)? (a) : (b)
```

Basically, it subtracts them, and looks at the sign-bit as a 1-or-0.
If the subtraction results in a negative number, the first parameter is smaller.

Comment: Assuming the type is 32-bits.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't actually work even for 32 bit integers, unless you believe that 2147483647 is smaller than -1.

Comment: @Stephen: What do you mean? In 2's compliment, it is smaller. (-1 has maximum value unsigned)

Comment: @GMan: -1 is unquestionably smaller than 2147483647, both as integers, and when compared in any signed type wide enough to represent both of them (32 bit twos complement integers, for example).  Unsigned comparisons have nothing to do with the issue.

Answer (score 12):

Typically:

```
#define min(a, b) (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
```

Be warned this evaluates the minimum twice, which was the reason for disaster in a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445514/returning-recursive-ternary-freaks-out/2445552#2445552).

But why would you want to obfuscate it?

---

This one stores the result in a variable, and only evaluates each argument once. It's basically a poor-mans inline function + declaration:

```
#define min(t, x, a, b) \
            t x; \
            { \
                t _this_is_a_unique_name_dont_use_it_plz_0_ = a; \
                t _this_is_a_unique_name_dont_use_it_plz_1_ = b; \
                x = _this_is_a_unique_name_dont_use_it_plz_0_ < \  
                    _this_is_a_unique_name_dont_use_it_plz_1_ ? \
                    _this_is_a_unique_name_dont_use_it_plz_0_ : \  
                    _this_is_a_unique_name_dont_use_it_plz_1_ ; \
            }
```

Use it like:

```
min(int, x, 3, 4)
/* x is an int, equal to 3
  Just like doing:

  int x = min(3, 4);

  Without double evaluation.
*/
```

Comment: It should be a little obfuscated - it's intended for another person who thinks he's programming-mastermind, that's why. Anyway, tnx.

Comment: A mastermind in which language? If we go to C++, I'm sure I can try to give him something to fry his expert noodle. But okay, what kind of assumptions can we make? Are these integers we're finding the minimum of? Then again, perhaps that's just a back-story to trick me into answering. :)

Comment: "I can give him something to fry his expert noodle" - glad to hear this, waiting further answers xD . BTW, the question was because in class we needed a simple minimum function, so i decided to go with macro so it'll look more c-ish.

Comment: I'd add another pair of parenthesis for even more safety:
#define min(a, b) ( ((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))

You could make a code block, evaluate the values to some variables and return the variables, so you just evaluate once. Bad code, anyway.

Comment: @Spidey: Agreed, added those parenthesis. I'll add your idea as well since this answer feels so empty.

Comment: Macro arguments should pretty much always be parenthesized in the macro. `min(int, x, 2; int c = 3, 4);` compiles as it's currently defined. OK, so what on earth is in the user's mind writing that? (Answer: the `=` sign in an object definition "binds" weaker than any operator, so it's the best example I could think of). But parenthesize `a`, and it doesn't parse, which is better. `t` is a notable exception - you can't parenthesize the type in an object definition since that turns it into a cast of an undefined object.

Comment: It worth to mention that GCC has `typeof` extension (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) that allows you avoid mentioning type name as macro param.

Comment: Woe if `a` or `b` happen to be named `r0` or `r1` though.

Comment: @jamesdlin: Yeah. There, that should do it. :P

Comment: @GMan - More useful (and (re)usable) would be to `#define _JOIN(x, y) x##y` / `#define JOIN(x, y) _JOIN(x, y)` / `#define UNIQ(x) JOIN(x, __LINE__)` and then use `UNIQ(x_)` and `UNIQ(y_)` to get uniquely named `x` and `y` variables.

Answer (score 5):

And, just for the hell of it, a GNU C example:

```
#define MAX(a,b) ({ \
    typeof(a) _a_temp_; \
    typeof(b) _b_temp_; \
    _a_temp_ = (a); \
    _b_temp_ = (b); \
    _a_temp_ = _a_temp_ < _b_temp_ ? _b_temp_ : _a_temp_; \
    })
```

It's not obfuscated, but I think this works for any type, in any context, on (almost, see comments) any arguments, etc; please correct if you can think of any counterexamples.

Comment: It's unlikely to happen, but this will be broken if `a` or `b` happen to themselves be variables named `_a_temp_` and `_b_temp_`.

Comment: Yeah, I thought on glueing on `__LINE__`, but it didnt seem worth the effort; if only there was a `__UNIQUE__` macro...

Comment: You would have deserved a much better score, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3437484/2436175 Maybe what missed was a bit of explanation about the reason for which this is safer.

Comment: it seems to be only gcc, not ISO C solution

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can use a #define for this, but why would you want to?  The problem with using #define, even with parentheses, is that you get unexpected results with code like this (okay, you wouldn't actually do this, but it illustrates the problem).

```
int result = min(a++, b++);
```

If you're using C++ not C, surely better to use an inline function, which (i) avoids evaluating the parameters more than once, and (ii) is type safe (you can even provide versions taking other types of value, like unsigned, double or string).

```
inline int min(int a, int b) { return (a < b) ? a : b; }
```

Comment: In C++, it should be a template function, for *any* type. And of course no need to rewrite it; there's already one in `<algorithm>`.

Comment: You can write an inline function in C99, too, or with compiler extensions (`__inline` in MSVC, `__inline__` in GNU C89).

Answer (score 3):

I think this method is rather cute:

`#define min(a, b) (((a) + (b) - fabs((a) - (b))) * 0.5)`

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make a simple macro with #define for returning the smaller of two numbers.

I wanted to add a solution when the *numbers* are *floating point*.

---

Consider when the numbers are floating point numbers and one of the numbers is [not-a-number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).  Then the result of `a < b` is always `false` regardless of the value of the other number.

```
// the result is `b` when either a or b is NaN
#define min(a, b) (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
```

It can be desirable that the result is as below where "NaN arguments are treated as missing data". C11 Footnote #242

```
a NaN  |  b NaN  |  a < b  |  min
-------+---------+---------+---------------
No     |  No     |  No     |  b
No     |  No     |  Yes    |  a
No     |  Yes    |  .      |  a
Yes    |  No     |  .      |  b
Yes    |  Yes    |  .      |  either a or b
```

To do so with a macro in C would simple wrap the `fmin()` function which supprts the above table.  Of course code should normally used the `fmin()` function directly.

```
#include <math.h>
#define my_fmin(a, b) (fmin((a), (b))
```

---

Note that  `fmin(0.0, -0.0)` may return `0.0` or `-0.0`.  They both have equal *value*.

Comment: the only answer which mentions `NaN`, problem which gets me to this SO

Answer (score 0):

If I were just trying to lightly obfuscate this I would probably go with something like:

```
#define min(a,b) ((a) + ((b) < (a) ? (b) - (a) : 0))
```

I think Doynax's solution is pretty cute, too.  Usual reservations for both about macro arguments being evaluated more than once.