# Is max(a,b) defined in stdlib.h or not?

Tags: c, visual-studio, macros, max, std

I'm using two computers, each with a different version of visual studio. On the visual studio 2008 computer my code compiles. On the visual 2010 computer my code doesn't compile because I'm using the macro `max(a,b)` which as far as I know is defined in stdlib.h. I cannot just define `max(a,b)` because it'll be a redefinition on the visual 2008 computer. But if I don't define `max(a,b)` my code doesn't compile on the visual 2010 computer.

Any solution?

Comment: Aside from the portability problems discussed in the accepted answer, I'm curious why you have problems with moving code using the `max()` macro from VS2008 to VS2010.  `max()` is defined in VS2010's `stdlib.h` in the same way that it is in VS2008 (there are options which will turn off the definition, but they're the same in both compilers).  In other words, there's something more than just the move from VS2008 to VS2010 (and that `max()` being defined in `stdlib.h` is non-standards conforming) that caused this problem for you.

Comment: On my Visual C the stdlib.h defines `__min` and `__max`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437404/min-and-max-in-c

Comment: In visual studio 2015, min and max are still defined in stdlib.h...

Comment: @Ruben, I had the same problem, running Visual Studio 2022 of `min()` and `max()` being defined in `stdlib.h` which was annoying because I had defined my own.  Solved it by defining `#define __STDC__ 1` before including `stdlib.h`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Any C library which defines a macro named `max` in its standard headers is broken beyond imagination. Fortunately, an easy workaround if you need to support such platforms is to `#undef max` (and any other problematic macros it defines) after including the system headers and before any of your own headers/code.

Note that everyone else is saying to wrap your definition in `#ifndef max ... #endif`. This is **not** a good idea. Defining `max` in a system header is an indication that the implementor was incompetent, and it's possible that certain versions of the environment have *incorrect* macros (for example, ones which do not properly protect arguments with parentheses, but I've even seen a `max` macro that was incorrectly performing `min` instead of `max` at least once in my life!). Just use `#undef` and be safe.

As for why it's so broken for `stdlib.h` to define `max`, the C standard is very specific about what names are reserved for the application and what names are reserved for standard functions and/or internal use by the implementation. There are very good reasons for this. Defining macro names in system headers that could clash with variable/function names used in the application program is dangerous. In the best case it leads to compile-time errors with an obvious cause, but in other cases it can cause very strange behavior that's hard to debug. In any case it makes it very difficult to write portable code because you never know what names will already be taken by the library.

Comment: Removed my answer: yours is best-suited, currently.

Comment: @R.. Thanks, but could you please explain why a C library which defines max is broken beyond imagination?

Comment: Your comments about why `<stdlib.h>` should not define `max` are valid up to a point.  If the user explicitly requests extra definitions that the implementation provides (for example, by defining `__EXTENSIONS__` (unofficial) or `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` (official)), then it is permissible for `<stdlib.h>` to provide extra definitions.  And on many platforms, the extensions may be enabled by default, and only made unavailable by requesting 'standard conformant mode'.

Comment: @Jonathan: it's also true, though, that defining unexpected macros is tougher on programmers than defining unexpected functions. The compiler errors (if any) are less likely to make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: Still, the example here (`max`) is very extreme. I would put that just one or two levels of badness below putting `#define i _Complex_I` in a standard header file. Also note that in this case, the only way of disabling the extension is by using another macro in the namespace reserved for the application (`#define NOMINMAX`) which rules out any hope of the implementation being conformant.

Comment: @R: the way to disable the extension is to set an option for the compiler (`/Za`).  The `NOMINMAX` configuration macro is for the Windows SDK and is not used by the C runtime library, so is strictly speaking outside the area of library standards conformance (though the extensive use of macros in the Windows SDK can be a real headache at times).

Comment: Gosh somebody's bitter about the subject! Gave you a vote up anyway.

Answer (score 11):

So answering your main question:

> Is max(a,b) defined in stdlib.h or not?

No it isn't, it's defined in windef.h around line 187:

> ```
> #ifndef NOMINMAX
>
> #ifndef max
> #define max(a,b)            (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
> #endif
>
> #ifndef min
> #define min(a,b)            (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
> #endif
>
> #endif  /* NOMINMAX */
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Protect it with an `#ifndef`.

```
#ifndef max
    #define max(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
#endif
```

Keep in mind that the version above is not as safe as an inline function, e.g. `max(a++,b--)` will cause unxpected results.

Comment: Your macro gives the minimum of the two numbers. Should be `(a) > (b)`

Comment: surprised nobody noticed for the last 5 years.  fixed!

Answer (score 0):

you can use condition compiling:

```
#ifndef max
  #define max(a,b) ...
#endif
```

Comment: `#undef max` would be much better. If MSVC is so broken as to define a `max` macro in the standard headers, can you really trust them to define it correctly? :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Visual C++, if you `#define NOMINMAX` before including the standard headers, you will not get a macro `max` or `min`.

Comment: That's yet another bug. If they'd made it `_NOMINMAX` instead, it would be conformant, but `NOMINMAX` is reserved for the application, and it's nonconformant for the standard library headers to use it for their own purpose.