# Using macros to extract the info that the typeof operator give us (in C language)

Tags: c, macros, typeof

i have a problem that i don't know if have solution (in C language)...

I want to combina a macro with the typeof "function" to obtain the name of a type in compilation time (because is C i'm not using polimorphism and other type of abstractions that difficult the task to the compiler)...

my problem: it seems to be impossible, every try i do, i only obtain thinks like

- "typeof(3)"
- "typeof(\"cat\")"
- Compilation errors...

it's possible to do it? It's only for experimentation, but i think that may be interesting to use in many codes.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: you should not. typeof() is a GCC extension to C language and it won't be portable.

Anyway, if you still want to use it, you can't do as you are describing. David Thornley's answer explains you why.

Comment: I think you're thinking of `typeid`

Answer (score 3):

C and C++ have multiple stages of compiling, and information generated in a later stage is not available for an earlier one.  Macro substitution is relatively early, and is traditionally part of the preprocessor.  `typeof()`, if you're using a system that implements C with such an extension, is going to apply to types of literals or variables.  That information is generated in a later stage, after what comes out of the preprocessor is parsed.

Therefore, you won't have `typeof()` information that you can use in a macro, and you'll have to find another way to do what you wanted to do (something like C++ templates?).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about GCC's `typeof`-construct extension to C.

Unfortunately, I don't think it will help with what you're trying to do - it's not an operator, it doesn't evaluate to some value.

It can only be used in certain scenarios, and (as far as I know) it has nothing to do with the preprocessor:

> A typeof-construct can be used anywhere a typedef name could be used

Answer (score 0):

gcc has the [`gcc typeof keyword`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html). Using that you are no longer compiling C, but something different a lot like C but not quite C.

Use at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `__typeof__` operator.

The `MINMAX` macro in C uses it. Standard C and Objective-C.

> [MIN and MAX in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437404/min-and-max-in-c/3437484#3437484)