# How to use __extension__ and __typeof__ in a minified example in C?

Tags: c, token

I saw there are such tokens in gcc's source code,

but how to use these `2` tokens?

Answer (score 22):

### __extension__:

> GCC uses the __extension__ attribute when using the -ansi flag to avoid
>   warnings in headers with GCC extensions.  This is mostly used in glibc
>   with function declartions using long long

### __typeof__:

[MIN and MAX in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437404/min-and-max-in-c/3437484#3437484) is a good example how it's used. Basically it allows you to declare a variable which has the same type as another variable.

Comment: Can you provide an minified example that uses these 2 tokens?

Comment: @assem ThiefMaster's answer should be more than good enough for you, unless you're trying to get someone else to do your homework.

Comment: @assem: There is no magic here. If you get a warning that you use an extension to the language, you can either change you code or add `__extension__` to tell the compiler that you **intended** to write unportable code, and it doesn't have to tell you that again. Otherwise it is of no use.

Comment: @assem: See [these clear examples](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html) to understand extension.