# How to implement a generic macro in C?

Tags: c, types, macros, generic-programming

```
FUNC(param);
```

When `param` is `char *`,dispatch to `func_string`.

when it's `int`,dispatch to `func_int`

I think there may be a solution to this,as variable types are known at compile time..

Comment: Even if this were possible, it would be fugly. C wasn't designed for it. Use structs and unions, you can even get run-time dispatch that way.

Answer (score 17):

This will be possible with [C1X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C1X) but not in the current standard.

It will look like this:

```
#define cbrt(X) _Generic((X), long double: cbrtl, \
                          default: cbrt, \
                          float: cbrtf)(X)
```

Comment: As this question pops up first on google: this is now possible using C11 http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic

Answer (score 11):

Variable types are known to the compiler, but not to the preprocessor (which sees the code simply as <strike>unstructured text</strike> a stream of tokens, and performs only simple replacement operations on it). So I am afraid you can't achieve this with C macros.

In C++, they invented templates to solve such problems (and more).

Comment: This is a false conclusion. The preprocessor does not need to know argument types, if you can arrange a macro expansion so that the *compiler* can perform do the analysis. See arnaud576875's answer how to solve this for the gnu compiler. Also, the preprocessor does not see the code as unstructured text, but as a *token stream*, which is a important difference.

Answer (score 6):

You can test for the characteristics of the types.

For example, `int` can hold a negative value, while `char*` can't. So if `((typeof(param))-1) < 0`, `param` is unsigned:

```
if (((typeof(param))-1) < 0) {
    do_something_with_int();
} else {
    do_something_with_char_p();
}
```

The compiler obviously optimizes this out.

Try it here: http://ideone.com/et0v1

This would be even easier if the types had different sizes. For example, if you want to write a generic macro than can handle different character sizes:

```
if (sizeof(param) == sizeof(char)) {
    /* ... */
} else if (sizeof(param) == sizeof(char16_t)) {
    /* ... */
} else if (sizeof(param) == sizeof(char32_t)) {
    /* ... */
} else {
   assert("incompatible type" && 0);
}
```

---

GCC has a [`__builtin_types_compatible_p()`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) builtin function that can check for types compatibility:

```
if (__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(param), int)) {
    func_int(param);
} else if (__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(param), char*)) {
    func_string(param);
}
```

Try it here: http://ideone.com/lEmYE

You can put this in a macro to achieve what you are trying to do:

```
#define FUNC(param) ({                                                \
    if (__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(param), int)) {           \
        func_int(param);                                              \
    } else if (__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(param), char*)) {  \
        func_string(param);                                           \
    }                                                                 \
})
```

(The `({...})` is a [GCC's statement expression](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs), it allows a group of statements to be a rvalue.

The [`__builtin_choose_expr()`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) builtin can choose the expression to compile. With __builtin_types_compatible_p this allows to trigger an error at compile-time if the type of param is not compatible with both `int` and `char*`: (by compiling somehting invalid in this case)

```
#define FUNC(param)                                                        \ 
    __builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(param), int) \ 
        , func_int(param)                                                  \ 
        , __builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(param), char*) \ 
            , func_string(param)                                           \ 
            , /* The void expression results in a compile-time error       \ 
                 when assigning the result to something.  */               \ 
            ((void)0)                                                      \ 
        )                                                                  \ 
    )
```

This is actually a slightly modified example from [__builtin_choose_expr docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Other-Builtins.html).

Comment: `func_int(x);`, `func_string(x);` and put the whole thing inside a `do { } while(0)`

Comment: I originally didn't enclosed the code in `do{}while()` because that was not a macro ;-)

Comment: -1 `typeof` is not C but also a gcc extension. What makes you think that an address can't have the 'sign' bit set?

Comment: `((char*) -1) < 0` is always false if the pointer type is unsigned. (assuming pointers are unsigned, aren't they ?)

Answer (score 4):

There is no possibility to run time check types in C89 / ANSI C, but there is an extension to gcc which allows it.  typeof or something along those lines if I remember.  I saw it in the Linux Kernel once.

In [kernel.h](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+*/tools/perf/util/include/linux/kernel.h#L41):

```
#define min(x, y) ({                \
typeof(x) _min1 = (x);          \
typeof(y) _min2 = (y);          \
(void) (&_min1 == &_min2);      \
_min1 < _min2 ? _min1 : _min2; })
```

Take a look at this article:  [GCC hacks in the Linux kernel](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-gcc-hacks/index.html)

When I first saw this I actually asked a question here on SO about:

[min macro in kernel.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595593/min-macro-in-kernel-h)

I'm not quite sure exactly how you would use it to solve your problem, but it's something worth taking a look at.

Comment: this is not a runtime type check - as C is not dynamically typed, type information is only available at compile-time

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a macro. Macro's value are substituted at compile time and are not intepreted. They are just substitutions.

Answer (score 1):

Variable types are indeed known at compile time, however macro expansion takes place before compilation. I suggest you implement 2 overloaded functions instead of a macro.

Answer (score 1):

my definition of a generic:
a structured abstract type which can only be fully defined with an input of other concrete types

this sounds exactly like a macro to me

pardon the psudo c code, my c is rusty

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// todo: ret=self needs vec3##generic_t##_copy(self, ret);
// not to mention we should probably be using __builtin_add_overflow
// __builtin_add_overflow might actually itself be a reasonably generics method example
// please bear with me
#define GENERIC_VEC3_ADD(generic_t) \
    generic_t vec3##generic_t##_add(generic_t self, generic_t other) {\
        generic_t ret = self;\
        ret[0] += other [0];;\
        ret[1] += other [1];\
        ret[2] += other [2];\
        return ret;\
    }

#define GENERIC_VEC3_FREPR(generic_t, printf_ts) \
    int vec3##generic_t##_frepr(generic_t self, FILE fd)\
        rerurn fprintf(fd, "<vec3##generic_t (##printf_ts##, printf_ts##, printf_ts##)>", \
        self[0], self[1], self[2]);\
    }

// here is the generic typedef, with some methods
#define GENERIC_VEC3(genetic_t, printf_ts) \
    typedef vec3##generic_t generic_t[3];\
    GENERIC_VEC3_ADD(generic_t) \
    GENERIC_VEC3_FREPR(generic_t, printf_ts)

// later we decide what types we want this genic for
GENERIC_VEC3(int, %ul)

// and use our generic
int main()
{
    vec3int foo = { 1, 2, 3 };;
    vec3int bar = { 1, 2, 3 };;
    vec3int sum = vec3int_add(foo, bar);
    vec3int_frepr(sum, stderr);
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    exit EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this is when you want to have a GENERIC_VEC3(int, %ul) and a GENERIC_VEC3(unsigned long long, %ull) in the same file.  Because `generic_t` is already typedef'd to one type, you can't reuse it in the same translation unit.