# GCC: Forbid implicit bool->int conversion

Tags: c++, gcc

Is there any gcc flag to forbid implicit `bool` to `int` conversion?

I want to get any warning with this code:

```
void function( int value, bool flag ) { }

int main()
{
  int a = 123;
  bool flag = true;

  //oops, a common mistake
  function( flag, a );
}
```

Comment: To use `bool` in C you need to `#include <stdbool.h>`

Comment: An implicit conversion is not a "cast". A cast, by definition, must be an explicit conversion. Also, are you asking about C or C++? They're different languages.

Comment: As to the error: your "common mistake" is easily detected by the fact that it also performs a **narrowing** conversion from `int` to `bool`. You can warn on that instead.

Comment: Removed the c tag, since this question doesn't appear to be about C. If that's wrong, please do add it back, but then remove the c++ tag.

Answer (score 6):

As a workaround, in C++11, you may delete the other possible overloads:

```
template <typename T> void function(int, T) = delete;
```

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question: no, there is no gcc flag to issue a warning in that case. Your problem was discussed several times on the gcc mailing list. For example [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2000-01/msg00771.html):

The main reason why this is not checked by the compiler lies in the fact that otherwise each statement like `if( intval )` would raise a warning too.

Comment: Summarizing: "Apparently, we disagree. As I don't see a need to change the compiler,
I won't do it myself. If you feel strongly that such a change is
needed, please send a patch to gcc-patches@gcc.gnu.org, changing the
compiler accordingly.

Regards,
Martin"

Answer (score 2):

Use a wrapper class:

```
class Boolean
{
    bool flag;
public:
    explicit Boolean(bool something){}

    bool getValue() const {return flag;}
    void setValue(bool a) {flag = a;}
};

void function(int value,Boolean flag ) { }

int main()
{
  int a = 123;
  Boolean flag(true);

  function( flag, a ); // fails! Boolean isn't a int value :)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In C, you can wrap a value in a generic-selection that only supports one type:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool x = true;
int y = _Generic(1, bool:2);

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", y);
}
```

This errors out (GCC 4.9), but will compile without complaint if you replace the `1` with `true` or `x`.

So for your example:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

void function( int value, bool flag ) { }
#define function(V, F) function(V, _Generic(F, bool:F))

int main() {
  int a = 123;
  bool flag = true;

  function( flag, a );  // error: '_Generic' selector of type 'int' is not compatible with any association
}
```

Comment: (this question was tagged C at time of answering, OP hasn't clarified)

Answer (score 2):

[clang-tidy](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/) will warn you, or even better, make this an error for you.

The test for this is [readability-implicit-bool-conversion](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/readability-implicit-bool-conversion.html). In earlier versions of the linter the test is named `readability-implicit-bool-cast`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the idea in the question [min macro in kernel.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595593/min-macro-in-kernel-h/5595690#5595690) you can use gcc's `typeof`

```
#include <stdbool.h>

#define function(x, y) do {                             \
                           __typeof(x) tmpone = (x);    \
                           int tmptwo = 0;              \
                           (void) (&tmpone == &tmptwo); \
                           fx((x), (y));                \
                       } while (0)

void fx(int value, bool flag) {
    (void)value;
    (void)flag;
}

int main(void) {
    int a = 123;
    bool flag = true;

    function(a, flag);
    function(flag, a); // oops, a common mistake
}
```