# spinlock initialization function

Tags: c, linux-kernel, mutex

To initialize a spinlock in kernel v4.19-rc5 one must use the `spin_lock_init` macro defined as follows:

```
#define spin_lock_init(_lock)               \
do {    \
       spinlock_check(_lock);               \
       raw_spin_lock_init(&(_lock)->rlock);     \
} while (0)
```

The function `spinlock_check(_lock)` just return `&lock->rlock`. [This](https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/SyncPrim/linux-sync-1.html) article explains that:

> The implementation of the spinlock_check is pretty easy, this function just returns the raw_spinlock_t of the given spinlock to be sure that we got exactly normal raw spinlock

I dont't understand how this function performs a **check**. I was expecting some `if` statements in a ckeck function. I'm sorry but I'm new to kernel programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't need any `if` statements because it exists for **compile time** checking.

You can see [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/spinlock.h) that most spinlock operations are defined as macros, so they are not able to restrict type of their argument.

Consider the following example:

```
struct not_a_spinlock {
    raw_spinlock_t rlock;
};
```

Without `spinlock_check` I could use `spin_lock_init` to initialize it:

```
struct not_a_spinlock spin;
spin_lock_init(&spin);
```

But thanks to `spinlock_check`, this will not work. This makes those macros type-restricted so they act more like functions.

The reason it returns `&lock->rlock` is due to convenience - its returned value can be passed to the next function.

So it could be worth rewriting the macro from your example as:

```
#define spin_lock_init(_lock)                         \
do {                                                  \
       raw_spin_lock_init(spinlock_check(_lock));     \
} while (0)
```

---

Similar techniques can be used with macros to somewhat restrict their argument types, like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595593/what-is-the-function-of-void-min1-min2-in-the-min-macro-in-kernel-h):

```
#define min(x, y) ({                \
    typeof(x) _min1 = (x);          \
    typeof(y) _min2 = (y);          \
    (void) (&_min1 == &_min2);      \
    _min1 < _min2 ? _min1 : _min2; })
```

Comment: I'm not convinced. In the call to `raw_spin_lock_init` the code accesses the same member and therefore the `spinlock_check` call seems still redundant here.

Comment: It does type checking. You cannot path arbitrary structure with rlock member like in my in example.