# Use of spinlock_check() function

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, spinlock

I have a question about the function [`spinlock_check()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/spinlock.h#L302) used in `spin_lock_init()` macro.

The code of `spinlock_check` is written below and it returns address of rlock

```
static __always_inline raw_spinlock_t *spinlock_check(spinlock_t *lock)
{
    return &lock->rlock;
}
```

It is used in the macro `spin_lock_init`. The code of this macro:

```
#define spin_lock_init(_lock)               \
do {                            \
   spinlock_check(_lock);               \
   raw_spin_lock_init(&(_lock)->rlock);     \
} while (0)
```

I saw a question about this topic in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52551594/spinlock-initialization-function).
But i did not quite understand and I want to express doubts in my way.

The `spin_lock_init()` is a macro but `spinlock_check()` isnt a macro. Its an inline function. So I think there is no way for some compilation magic to happen here but I expect some magic during execution of those instructions.
 What effect does `spinlock_check()`  has?
Because nothing is using the return value of `spinlock_check()` function.
Even though `spinlock_check()` return something the next step is going to get executed anyways.
Because I saw its usage in one of the file and I thought that its different from min(x, y) macro.

Here is the usage which I [found](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/char/random.c#L813)

```
#ifdef CONFIG_NUMA
static void do_numa_crng_init(struct work_struct *work)
{
    int i;
    struct crng_state *crng;
    struct crng_state **pool;

    pool = kcalloc(nr_node_ids, sizeof(*pool), GFP_KERNEL|__GFP_NOFAIL);
    for_each_online_node(i) {
        crng = kmalloc_node(sizeof(struct crng_state),
                    GFP_KERNEL | __GFP_NOFAIL, i);
        spin_lock_init(&crng->lock);
        crng_initialize(crng);
        pool[i] = crng;
    }
    mb();
    if (cmpxchg(&crng_node_pool, NULL, pool)) {
        for_each_node(i)
        kfree(pool[i]);
        kfree(pool);
    }
}
```

So here `crng` is dynamically allocated one. say I have missed the `kmalloc` code meaning I haven't allocated memory for `crng` but still I used the macro spin_lock_init(crng).
Now what good the `spinlock_check()` function does ?
Isn't it that after `spinlock_check()` function `raw_spin_lock_init` automatically executes ?

If it is going to execute then whats the use of `spinlock_check()` function?
 There should be some meaning but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

What you are missing is that `spinlock_check()` does not perform any check **at run time**. That's why its returned value is ignored. This instruction is expected to be removed during compilation by the optimizer.

Is it of any use, then? Yes! It's purpose is to ensure **at compile time** that the type of its parameter is `spinlock_t *`. If you don't give a pointer to `spinlock_t` as a parameter to `spin_lock_init()`, you will trigger a compilation error.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering.

 just for my clarity, So if we take the above example then the entire thing is only to check type of  crng->lock isnt it ?
But isnt crng->lock a dynamically allocated one? 
And during type check does it really matter for a compiler whether a variable is dynamically created one or not?

Comment: @srikarsana What matters for a compiler is how the variable is declared, not how it is allocated. `crng` points to a [`struct crng_state`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.11/source/drivers/char/random.c#L412) and there is no doubt that `crng->lock` is then of the expected type (`spinlock_t`).