# How to fix these MIN, MAX macros?

Tags: c, gcc

I am getting the following warning:

```
warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect
```

The macros are defined below. I am compiling with GCC (4.4.3) on Linux. It is C code.

```
#define MY_MAX(a,b) \
   ({ __typeof__ (a) _a = (a); \
       __typeof__ (b) _b = (b); \
     _a > _b ? _a : _b; })

#define MY_MIN(a,b) \
   ({ __typeof__ (a) _a = (a); \
       __typeof__ (b) _b = (b); \
     _a < _b ? _a : _b; })
```

How do I fix them to get rid of the warnings?

**[[Update]]**

Actually, I found the cause of the warning. It had nothing to do with the macro itself. It was because I was trying to find the min of two numbers, one of which was a #def named as MAXIMUM_ARRAYSIZE. It was defined as:

```
#define MAXIMUM_ARRAYSIZE (sizeof(size_t)==2,16384,1073741824)
```

That is a pretty strange macro definition.

Comment: Could you show the call site where the warning is triggered? (Tagged GCC, the macros use a GCC extension.)

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437404/min-and-max-in-c) help?

Comment: I don't see a single comma in the code here. So I guess the problem is in the code that uses the macro (which probably contains a comma), not the macro itself.

Comment: What arguments are you using to produce the warning?

Answer (score 1):

The error is not in your macro definition.

You'll need to show us the calling code to the `MIN`/`MAX` macros. It sounds like you're either trying to use the result of `MIN`/`MAX` as incorrectly, or you've passed a token (`a` or `b`) containing an unexpected comma.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and it worked fine without any warnings/error with `gcc -Wall`. Check how you're using those macros!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MY_MAX(a,b) \
   ({ __typeof__ (a) _a = (a); \
       __typeof__ (b) _b = (b); \
     _a > _b ? _a : _b; })

#define MY_MIN(a,b) \
   ({ __typeof__ (a) _a = (a); \
       __typeof__ (b) _b = (b); \
     _a < _b ? _a : _b; })

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d \n", MY_MAX(10,20));
    printf("%d \n", MY_MIN(10,20));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc ma.c -Wall
$ ./a.out 
20 
10 
$
```

Answer (score -2):

`_a < _b ? _a : _b` is an expression, not a statement, but you have written it as a statement (all by itself followed by a semicolon).

Comment: `({...})` is a GCC extension that *is* an expression (which evaluated to the result of the last "statement"). If it wasn't, you'd get a syntax error instead. And if that was somehow averted, you'd probably get a different warning (e.g. "statement has no effect") - there's no comma operator in the macro.