# read line and read three letters at a time in C

Tags: c, lines, letter

I'm having a problem when trying to read 3 letter each time, I want to read line by line and in each line to read sequentially 3 letters at a time.

when read the line when finding the \n jumps to the next line...

i try this

```
while ((getline(&line, &lenght, file)) != -1){
   while ((strncpy(ch, line, 3)) != NULL) { 

        let = replaceletter(tab, ch);

        if (let != 0)
            printf("%c", let);
   }
}
```

but it does not work, just read the first 3 letters and I wanted the entire line.
I really do not know how to do this, I need help, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand how the second while loop is supposed to work.   strncpy returns s1, IE ch in this case.  ch had better be a char *.

So.. how is ch ever going to == NULL, unless it already was NULL to start off with?   And if ch is NULL to start off with (the initialisation of it is not shown) then it's already a segfault :)

It might make sense if this line were

```
while(*(strncpy(ch, line, 3)) != NULL)) {
```

HTH

Comment: the ch is declared as: char *ch;

Comment: @user1364304: If you have `char *ch;` and copy a string into it, then you are in trouble.

Comment: @vlad-lazarenko In the C language, the only legitimate thing to copy a string to is a char *.   man strncpy tells us: 
`     Name

strcpy, strncpy - copy a string

Synopsis

#include <string.h>

char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);

char *strncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n);`

Comment: @GreenAsJade: You are wrong about legitimate copy destinations. But that's not the point. The point is that passing uninitialized `ch` to `strncpy` is UB.

Comment: @vlad-lararenko. I agree that this is the point.  I was responding to your comment that if you have a char * and copy a string to it you are in trouble.  In fact, you must have a char * as the destination of a string copy.  As you say, the char * that you have must also be initialised :)    Maybe you ommitted the word "uninitialised", maybe you meant "if you have an uninitialised char *"?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably run into problems when your line is < 3 characters long. Try a  better, more-robust way to specify the number of bytes that strncpy should copy, like using some sort of Min function implementation in C (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437404/min-and-max-in-c)).

Comment: the text file I want to read is already prepared for be read 3 at a time the problem is the \n at the end of the line

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that could have been done better in your code:

1. The code does not check how many characters were read. Was a line too short?
2. It is not clear why the return of `strncpy` is being checked for `NULL`. It does not return `NULL`.
3. It is not clear whether you initialize `line` and `lenght` and to what values.
4. Unfortunately, it is hard to be a psychic and guess what is `replaceletter`, what it does,  and how `tab` and `ch` are declared.
5. It is a mystery as for why `strncpy` is called in a `while` loop.
6. It seems like your program does not account for a newline character being a part of the returned string.

In other words, if you want to get more or less adequate help, it is always a good idea to provide a small, complete and working example demonstrating your problem.

If I were assigned that task, I'd probably write it like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
    int  ret     = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    char    *line    = NULL;
    size_t   linecap = 0;
    ssize_t  len;

    do {
        len = getline(&line, &linecap, stdin);
        if (len == -1) {
            if (errno != 0) {
                perror("readline");
                ret = EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            break;
        }
        if (len < 4)
            continue; /* Line is too short, try again */
        /* printf("The line is: %s", line); */
        printf("First three letters are: '%.*s'\n", 3, line);
    } while(1);

    free(line); /* It is always a good idea to cleanup after yourself */
    return ret;
}
```

I hope that the above snippet is self-explanatory. But if there is something that needs clarification then please don't hesitate to ask.

Good Luck!