# How can I write a 'clamp' / 'clip' / 'bound' macro for returning a value in a given range?

Tags: objective-c, c, macros, predefined-macro

I often find myself writing something like

```
int computedValue = ...;
return MAX(0, MIN(5, computedValue));
```

I would like to be able to write this as a single one-line macro. It must be free of side effects, in the same way that the existing system macros MIN and MAX are, and should work for the same data types as MIN and MAX.

Can anyone show me how to turn this into a single macro?

Comment: Can't you simply do that, define a min-max macro, _using_ the min and max macros? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: It is usually called `clamp`.

Comment: Just for curiosity, is there any reason not to use std::min and std::max from the C++ standard library ?

Comment: @kebs I'm mostly in objective-c. It does not fall naturally to use c++ functions :)

Comment: @ybungalobill Or bound, or clipped, or ... I think the most usual denomination depends on the application domain.

Comment: Well, then, maybe remove the C++ tag, as C++ programmers tend to avoid macros, especially if the standard library provides a much better solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is without side effects and works for any primitive number:

```
#define MIN(A,B)    ({ __typeof__(A) __a = (A); __typeof__(B) __b = (B); __a < __b ? __a : __b; })
#define MAX(A,B)    ({ __typeof__(A) __a = (A); __typeof__(B) __b = (B); __a < __b ? __b : __a; })

#define CLAMP(x, low, high) ({\
  __typeof__(x) __x = (x); \
  __typeof__(low) __low = (low);\
  __typeof__(high) __high = (high);\
  __x > __high ? __high : (__x < __low ? __low : __x);\
  })
```

Can be used like so

```
int clampedInt = CLAMP(computedValue, 3, 7);
double clampedDouble = CLAMP(computedValue, 0.5, 1.0);
```

Other suggested names instead of `CLAMP` can be `VALUE_CONSTRAINED_LOW_HIGH`, `BOUNDS`, `CLIPPED`.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from this site http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.34/glib-Standard-Macros.html#CLAMP:CAPS

```
#define CLAMP(x, low, high)  (((x) > (high)) ? (high) : (((x) < (low)) ? (low) : (x)))
```

Comment: Oh, side effects. `CLAMP(getchar(), low++, high--)`

Comment: That's right. Good point!!! So that's why we should do like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437404/min-and-max-in-c/3437484#3437484 and not use the default MIN and MAX like @VosobeKapsimanis suggests.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to try it like that:

```
template <class T> 
const T& clamp(const T& value, const T& low, const T& high) {
    return value < low ? low:
           value > high? high:
                         value;
}
```

Comment: Or `return std::max( low, std::min( high, value ) );`

Answer (score 1):

```
 #define MAX(a, b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b)) 
 #define MIN(a, b) (((a) > (b)) ? (b) : (a))
```

making it in one #define directive isn't going to be very readable.

Answer (score -1):

Using just one compare operation:

```
static inline int clamp(int value, int min, int max) {
    return min + MIN((unsigned int)(value - min), max - min)
}
```

Comment: Well. Say the type of the value can change - I would prefer a macro? Do you agree?

Comment: Yeah, would require some way to make "unsigned typeof" to turn it into macro.

Comment: On the other hand assuming we're working with integral types only, `#define CLAMP(x, low, high) ({ typeof(low) _low = (low); LARGE_ENOUGH_UNSIGNED_TYPE _x = (x) - _low, _high = (high) - _low; (typeof(x)) MIN(_x, _high); })`