# Is there a Objective-C or C math function to constrain a variable between a Min and a Max?

Tags: objective-c, c, math, max, clamp

What I am looking for is a math function that constrains a primitive variable between a minimum and a maximum value in only one single function call, if it exists, in the standard math libraries for Objective-C.

I currently use:

```
float constrainedValue = fminf( maxValue, fmaxf( minValue, inValue ) );
```

Since I know that both `fminf` and `fmaxf` could potentially have instruction jumps or branches, it seems likely there could be a simple routine that could conjoin both of these operations into one, optimized function.

Comment: There is `boost::algorithm::clamp(n, lower, upper);`

Comment: Related (solution using a macro): [How can I write a 'clamp' / 'clip' / 'bound' macro for returning a value in a given range?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14770282/4573247)

Answer (score 1):

This topic is thoroughly discussed here: [Fastest way to clamp a real (fixed/floating point) value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427477/fastest-way-to-clamp-a-real-fixed-floating-point-value)

'clamp' is the keyword I was looking for.