# Implementing min() and max() in Clang without double evaluation

Tags: c, clang

The classic preprocessor version of the `min` function looks like

```
#define min(a, b) ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

This leaves you open to double evaluation—the situation in which you do `min(f(), g())`, forgetting that `f` or `g` has side effects, and you have to spend hours trying to figure out why your function is running twice. To prevent this, you can do

```
#define min(a, b) ({__typeof__(a) _a = (a); \
    __typeof__(b) _b = (b); \
    _a < _b ? _a : _b;})
```

This works great under GCC, but if you run it through Clang with `-Wgnu` set—this set of warnings falls under the umbrella of `-pedantic`—you get errors like

```
test.c:5:10: error: use of GNU statement expression extension [-Werror,-Wgnu]
        int a = min(3, 7);
                ^
test.c:1:22: note: expanded from macro 'min'
#  define min(a, b) ({__typeof__(a) _a = (a); __typeof__(b) _b = (b); _a < _b ? _a : _b;})
```

Is it possible to define these macros in a way that prevents double evaluation *and* which is acceptable to Clang under `-pedantic`? (Yes, you can disable the warning with `-Wno-gnu`, in which case Clang handles the statement expression without a problem. I’m asking because I, like `clang -pedantic`, am too picky for my own good.)

**Edit:** I am working in C. I tagged this C++ too because I thought a solution might apply to C++ as well as to C. Oops—forgot about templates! Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: I am curious why both *C* and *C++* tags, which language are you targetting? The answer is different depending on the language.

Comment: Simply don't use the preprocessor for it, period. An inline function does the job better and in a more obvious way. And I think in C++ you can even use templates to avoid creating multiple functions for different types.

Comment: C or C++. C++ use templates.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour based on the compiler error he's targeting C

Comment: @ThiefMaster: But an inline function in C cannot be generic and neither can it be overloaded by type. Which is why people continue to be tempted to use macros for this kind of thing, to avoid writing `min_int`, `min_unsigned_int`, `min_double` etc.

Comment: `...and you have to spend hours trying to figure out why your function is running twice`. Exactly! Congratulations, you empirically proved one of the core arguments against using function-like macros to be right: macros are a complete mess to debug and maintain. Now... how long does it take you to write `MIN` as a proper, bug-free, working function? 10 seconds? 20?

Comment: @Lundin: It's non-trivial in C.

Comment: I think you could get quite a good solution in C with `_Generic`.

Comment: Why is a C++ answer accepted for this question, where you clearly state that you want C and a C version exists?

Comment: @JensGustedt The accepted answer provided a link to a long discussion that concluded with “don’t use the preprocessor for this”. The C answer was less satisfactory to me.

Comment: @bdesham, I don't understand, the link doesn't add much to what you already had in your question. Can you elaborate, please, why the C answer is less satisfactory? As it appears now, this is a C++ answer to a C question, so it will not serve many others.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Because the question did not clearly state that he wanted C at the time that the answer was written, and because a C version does _not_ exist. I say that in my answer, with a reference which is a HUGE previous question on the topic. Please read it. That the answer adds little new to the question is because the OP was _right_, and there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: what I don't get about that, is that there *is* a C solution for that, now, and it is given in the other answer. The answers in your link dates from 2010 and are kind of obsolete. There is a new version of C since two years now that provides the tools for that.

Comment: @JensGustedt To be honest I was hoping for a terse solution like the “classic version” I mentioned in my question. I already know how to write a `min` function for `int`s, a different one for `long`s, and so on; my point in asking was to find something that didn’t require so much boilerplate. The answer by @Simple was almost entirely boilerplate.

Comment: @bdesham it is boilerplate that you only have to write once though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're really writing in C++, simply *don't use the preprocessor*:

```
template <typename T>
const T min(const T& a, const T& b)
{
   return (b < a) ? b : a;
}
```

<sup>(Note that I've swapped `b` and `a`, so that you get the left-hand operand if the two are equal.)</sup>

Otherwise [no, not really](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3437404/560648).

Comment: I'd prefer `return (b<a)?b:a;` for stability.

Comment: There is no reason whatsoever to use the preprocessor for this, C or C++ doesn't matter. I'm curious why you would write a function `min` for this in C++ though. Why not overload the `<` operator? It is the very same thing, and this function here will force you to overload `<` anyhow, in case you pass objects to it.

Comment: @Lundin: Because the `<` operator does not pick one of two operands. It gives you a boolean. Show us your genius C solution.

Comment: Here is an article where Andrei Alexandrescu gets very het up about the correct way to write a `min`/`max` function template: http://www.drdobbs.com/generic-min-and-max-redivivus/184403774.

Comment: I am using C (see the edit to the question), so I guess my answer is the “no, not really” part :-)

Comment: Even as a C++ answer this isn't a good one, since this doesn't capture the case that `a` and `b` may have different types.

Comment: @Jens: That's quite deliberate, actually. I choose to enforce that this operation be defined only between two expressions of the _same_ type. It's rare that there's a _good_ way to define `<` between two non-numeric types. You want to convert on the way in? Go right ahead.

Comment: How hard can it be to pick one of the operands from outside the function, if you call the code as `if(a < b) use(a); else use(b);` Seems far more compact and readable to me. Assuming `<` is overloaded `operator <` in C++.

Comment: @bdesham If you are using C then 1) why tag it as C++ and 2) why accept a C++ answer. You don't make any sense.

Comment: @Lundin: It is not "a C++ answer".

Comment: It is written in C++ and will not compile in C.

Comment: @Lundin: I guess you failed to read the _whole_ answer. There are two parts to it.

Answer (score 8):

I think this would work as a C11 solution.

```
inline
int min(int const x, int const y)
{
    return y < x ? y : x;
}

inline
unsigned minu(unsigned const x, unsigned const y)
{
    return y < x ? y : x;
}

inline
long minl(long const x, long const y)
{
    return y < x ? y : x;
}

inline
unsigned long minul(unsigned long const x, unsigned long const y)
{
    return y < x ? y : x;
}

inline
long long minll(long long const x, long long const y)
{
    return y < x ? y : x;
}

inline
unsigned long long minull(unsigned long long const x, unsigned long long const y)
{
    return y < x ? y : x;
}

inline
float minf(float const x, float const y)
{
    return y < x ? y : x;
}

inline
double mind(double const x, double const y)
{
    return y < x ? y : x;
}

inline
long double minld(long double const x, long double const y)
{
    return y < x ? y : x;
}

#define MIN(X, Y) (_Generic((X) + (Y),   \
    int:                min,             \
    unsigned:           minu,            \
    long:               minl,            \
    unsigned long:      minul,           \
    long long:          minll,           \
    unsigned long long: minull,          \
    float:              minf,            \
    double:             mind,            \
    long double:        minld)((X), (Y)))
```

Comment: +1 but your `_Generic` expression is much too complicated. `_Generic((X)+(Y), int : min, unsigned : minu, ...)((X), (Y))` would suffice. Also you have forgotten the floating point types.

Comment: @JensGustedt thanks. I don't think there's a way to get this to work for pointers though without requiring a `void*` cast.

Comment: Pointers could be done through a `default` case, only that the choice expression as it is now wouldn't work for pointers :(

Comment: @JensGustedt I think you'd lose the nicer error message then though if you tried to pass a `struct` or something.

Answer (score 4):

The C11 solution posted by Simple looks ideal, but in case you don't have a C11 compiler, you could still define a macro with intristic type safety (as type safe as C gets anyhow) :

```
#define MIN(type, X, Y) min_ ## type(X, Y)
```

This macro will only allow implemented types to be passed, otherwise you will get a compiler error.

Example:

```
#define MIN(type, X, Y) min_ ## type(X, Y)

long  min_long  (long x, long y);
char  min_char  (char x, char y);
float min_float (float x, float y);

int main()
{
  long  min_l = MIN (long, 5L, 10L);
  char  min_c = MIN (char, 'A', 'B');
  float min_f = MIN (float, 666.66f, 3.14f);

  printf("%ld\n", min_l);
  printf("%c\n", min_c);
  printf("%f\n", min_f);
}

char  min_char  (char x, char y)    { return x < y ? x : y; }
long  min_long  (long x, long y)    { return x < y ? x : y; }
float min_float (float x, float y)  { return x < y ? x : y; }
```

Now if you would execute the above macro with `MIN(int, 1, 2)`, you would get a compiler error: "`min_int`, no such function exists".