# memset is not working properly

Tags: c, linux, memcpy, libc

I have the following set of code not able to find why I am getting garbage value.My intention is to copy the number of byte as destination irrespective of source to make a generic copy for my application. But not getting the correct result.Is there any way to achieve this.

```
int main()
{
    char x[6];
    char *i="pra";
    memset(&x,0,6); //Doing memset

    memcpy(&x,i,6);
    printf("%x %x %x %x %x %x",x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],x[5]);
}

o/p:
70 72 61 0 25 78
```

We can see the output after 0 is garbage.But why it is comming and where it is comming.
whey memset not working properly.
Pleae help to get the cause of this concept.

Comment: Use `strncpy(x, i, sizeof x);` instead of `memset/memcpy` to copy as much of `i` as possible without over/under filling `x`, padding with 0 if needed.

Answer (score 6):

You're copying six bytes from `i` to `x`, but only have four bytes of non-garbage values in `i`, so the last two are whatever happened to be after `i`.

Comment: After i means .. what? Is that in text or which segment.

Comment: @pradipta: Reading past the end of an array, which is what you are doing, is undefined behavior. It's a bug and you should fix it.

Comment: Thanks Blastfurnace but .. If I use the length of source then that also lead to bug in case the source is less than that..

Comment: @pradipta: That's why you must __know__ the size of your source and destination and code appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

You are copying 6 bytes of i while its length is 4. Doing that will solve the problem:

```
memcopy(&x, i, strlen(i));
```

Comment: In that case if the x is smaller than the source then undefined behavior will be the result

Comment: 1) it's `memcpy`; 2) this will needlessly walk `i` twice and won't NUL-terminate `x`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia is right. That's exactly the purpose `strcpy()` and `strncpy()` have been invented for.

Comment: You can do a *MIN(strlen(i) + 1, 6)* where the min macro can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437404/min-and-max-in-c)

Comment: Thanks Nicop,Yes I also though this to do..It will give a way to copy generic way.

Comment: @glglgl: careful, `strncpy` is an unfortunate historic accident, and does not do what most people think it does (most importantly, it won't terminate the buffer if the source string is as big as the buffer).

Comment: @MatteoItalia Right, but it is possible to cope with that (just manually add a `'\0'` and give `strncpy()` a number reduced by 1).

Answer (score 2):

**memset()** is working properly. But **memcpy()** coping junk data to buffer.

```
int main()
{
    char x[6];
    char *i="pra";
    memset(&x,0,6); //Doing memset
    printf("%x %x %x %x %x %x",x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],x[5]); // All will be 0 here
    memcpy(&x,i,6); //6 bytes here mentioned is reponsible for that values
    printf("%x %x %x %x %x %x",x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],x[5]);
}
```

Comment: Junk from where.I need to implement a generic copy irrespective of the source length.The length should be the destination.

Comment: @pradipta: this is not possible.

Comment: @pradipta, these junk from stack may be. because x[] is local.