# Suggestions for improving the readability of this code

Tags: c, code-readability

I am not sure whether I should ask this here or to some other StackExchange site, but I will go on... Please migrate if it is not suitable here)

I am reviewing a code. Requirement is to call a function `n`number of times with argument ranging from 0 to `n`. But if `n`is greater than 7, call the function only 7 times.

My colleague implemented it as follows:

```
void ExecuteFunctions(U8 count)
{
    if(count > 0) oprA(0);
    if(count > 1) oprA(1);
    if(count > 2) oprA(2);
    if(count > 3) oprA(3);
    if(count > 4) oprA(4);
    if(count > 5) oprA(5);
    if(count > 6) oprA(6);
    if(count > 7) oprA(7);
}
```

I modified it to:

```
void ExecuteFunctions(U8 count)
{
    for(U8 loopcnt = 0; loopcnt < count; loopcnt++)
    {
        oprA(loopcnt);

        if(loopcnt == 7)
        {
            // We don't want to execute this function more number of times if it is already executed 7 times
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But I still feel that there could be a better way and need your inputs.
(Also please migrate if it is off topic here)

Comment: Let the compiler optimize it. It will probably unroll the loop for you.

Comment: @AustinMullins Nice idea but Optimization is turned off.  And you can say, it became like a Programming riddle for me now!

Comment: Optimization for readability or performance ?

Comment: You can move the `loopcnt < 8` condition to the loop condition. It won't optimize it, but make it a bit more compact.

Comment: The question is unclear: `0` to `7` is already `8` times.  is `n` included in the range or not?  Both your code and your colleague's don't seem to implement the spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MIN is a macro useful and often defined

```
#define MIN(a,b)     (((a) > (b)) ? (b) : (a))
#define MAX_STEP 7

void ExecuteFunctions(U8 count)
{
    int loopcnt = 0;
    count = MIN(count, MAX_STEP);

    while(loopcnt++ < count) {
        oprA(loopcnt);   
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also mention about pitfalls `MIN` macro has. [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3437484/3866447) will be also useful here.

Comment: `while(loopcnt++ < count)` should be changed to `for (loopcnt = 0; loopcnt < count; loopcnt++)` otherwise `oprA()` is called with incremented values.

Answer (score 2):

Let the compiler optimize it. I feel like the following is slightly more readable:

```
void ExecuteFunctions(U8 count)
{
    for(U8 loopcnt = 0; loopcnt < count && loopcnt < 8; loopcnt++)
    {
        oprA(loopcnt);
    }
}
```

Of course, you'll need to run a profiler to actually evaluate the performance of your program.

Comment: Nice `for` loop.  Note: `swtich()` calls `oprA()` in the reverse order.

Comment: Right, that's why I said "if the order doesn't matter".

Comment: Why yes you did - another example of quick reading and code speaking louder than documentation.

Comment: This code calls `oprA()` one extra time for `count < 8`, but if neither order nor accuracy matter...

Comment: I wonder why no one caught that earlier. I'll cut out the switch statement part.

Answer (score 1):

I would write it as

```
void ExecuteFunctions(unsigned count) {
    // Could use min() too if available.
    unsigned iters = count < 7 ? count : 7;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < iters; ++i)
        oprA(i);
}
```

The size of the code generated for this function is ~36 bytes on X86_64 with GCC 4.9 and `-O3`. The size of the original version is 141 bytes (GCC doesn't seem to be very smart with it).

Note that passing plain `int`s, `unsigned int`s, `size_t`s, etc., is usually better than narrowing a parameter just because you know the value will be small. The compiler often has an easier time generating good code for variables that have a natural size for the architecture. An exception is when you need to store large amounts of data.

**Update:**

The following version (modified a tiny bit from Austin's answer -- sorry for stealing it :)) gives 32 bytes by the way. I think I prefer it.

```
void ExecuteFunctions(unsigned count) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < count && i < 8; ++i)
        oprA(i);
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as stealing on SO. The best answer will eventually emerge. No need to mention me in yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
void ExecuteFunctions(U8 count)
{
    for(U8 loopcnt = 0; loopcnt < (count & 7); loopcnt++)
    {
        oprA(loopcnt);
    }
}
```

Comment: That will call it zero times for `count == 8`. Might be some similar trick though...

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* like `switch` statements, try this and see if it survives code review:

```
void ExecuteFunctions(U8 count) {
    int i = 0;
    switch (count) {
      default: oprA(i++);
      case 6:  oprA(i++);
      case 5:  oprA(i++);
      case 4:  oprA(i++);
      case 3:  oprA(i++);
      case 2:  oprA(i++);
      case 1:  oprA(i++);
      case 0:  oprA(i);
    }
}
```