# Macro for defining min function

Tags: c

Having this statement:

```
dist[i]= min(dist[i],dist[j]+edge[j][i]);
```

How safe the corresponding following macro (in C) is:

```
#define MIN(d[i], edge[i][j]) (d[i] < edge[i][j] ? (d[i]) : (edge[i][j]))
```

Thank you.

Comment: Perfectly safe, because you aren't using it. But why not write a function?

Comment: Does that even compile?

Comment: That's not a proper macro definition. Arguments to a macro should be simple identifiers, not array references.

Comment: No, it gives me an error that why I am posting this because I thought it includes a side effects

Comment: BTW, it is a FAQ. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3437484/841108)

Comment: *I thought it includes side effects* doesn't really explain why you might have array references as arguments to a macro. Surely, macros can have side effects. But that has nothing to do with argument declaration syntax. You really should look at C documentation for how macros work. Things don't work just like you think they might.

Comment: @JacksonArms What do you think macros do? From the looks of it, you might have some conceptual problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a Min definition macro you need to do it like that

```
#define MIN(a, b) (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
```

Like said in comment, macros need identifiers and not array, not even variables. But this macros is note type safe. Why not using fmax and fmin? It's better and you dont have to create a macro