# Macro result malfunction in an operation

Tags: c, macros

I tried with this macro:

```
#define min(x,y) x<y? x:y
```

It's supposed to return the minimum and it does. The only problem is when trying to use the result of that macro in an operation, it doesn't work.

Example

```
x=min(3,4);
```

Here x will naturally have 3 as a value, but when trying this:

```
x= 23 + min(3,4);
```

the result will still always be 3 (the result of the macro), no matter what number I add to it (23 was arbitrary in there).
May I know why this happens?

Comment: When I try your code the result is 4, not 3.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/alrhCf

Comment: LESSON: don't use macro's where you should use functions

Comment: As always when facing a problem with macros, use a compiler switch to check what the preprocessor made of it.

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437404/min-and-max-in-c

Comment: @Jongware I work with dev c++. How can I do that?

Comment: Does it come with a manual?

Answer (score 2):

`min` should be defined as:

```
#define min(a,b)  (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
```

You also seem to be mixing `MIN` and `min`. C is case sensitive, so `min()` could be calling something else.

```
#define min(X,Y) X<Y? X:Y  // I changed MIN to lowercase here
x= 23 + min(3,4);
```

-> will expand to:

```
x = 23 + 3 < 4 ? 3 : 4;
```

which is the same as:

```
x = (23 + 3) < 4 ? 3 : 4;
```

That's why parentheses are needed:

```
x = 23 + ((3 < 4) ? 3 : 4);
```

To avoid further problems with for example: `min(x | b + 4 / 2, y && 0x01 + 3);`, parentheses are added around all the values:

```
(((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
```

When using such macro's, **care should be taken with the following**:

```
int y = 1;
int z = 2;

x = min(y++, z++);
```

This evaluates to:

```
x = ((y++ < z++) ? y++ : z++); // some parentheses omitted
```

Which is not wat we want. `y` or `z` will be incremented twice.

Comment: @Jdoe - I'm adding more info

Comment: as a matter of fact I used I defined it as min not MIN and I tried it with a whole different name and still the same thing.

Comment: @Jdoe - So, never say too fast: _"min works just fine"_ :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is operator assocativity and precedence. When you expand the macro, it becomes:

```
x = 23 + 3 < 4 ? 3 : 4;
```

which is interpreted as:

```
x = (23 + 3) < 4 ? 3 : 4;
```

because arithmetic has higher precedence than comparison operators. You should wrap the expansion in parentheses to force it to be treated as a single expression.

```
#define min(x,y) (x<y? x:y)
```

You should also put parenthese around the uses of each parameter, in case they're expressions with operators that have lower precedence than `<`.

```
#define min(x,y) ( (x) < (y) ? (x) : (y) )
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/Hf7KKM)

But using a macro for a function like this is still a bad idea. All the repetitions of the parameters mean that you can't use it with expressions with side effects. E.g. `min(i++, j++)` will increment one of the variables twice. It would be better to use an inline function.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example of why parenthesis in macros is important.

This:

```
x= 23 + min(3,4);
```

Expands to this:

```
x= 23 + 3<4? 3:4;
```

Which, with implicit parenthesis, is the same as:

```
x= ((23 + 3)<4)? 3:4;
```

This evaluates to 4.

If you define your macro like this:

```
#define min(x,y) ((x)<(y)?(x):(y))
```

Then you get this:

```
x= 23 + ((3)<(4)?(3):(4));
```

The ternary evaluates to 3, so x is assigned 26.

Comment: Oh my! thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's because + has the highest precedence, < is next and ? has the lowest precedence.  So,

```
23 + min(3,4)
```

expands to

```
23 + 3 < 4 ? 3 : 4
```

So, the addition is done first, and then you'd have:

```
26 < 4 ? 3 : 4
```

Then the relational operator is done, and you'd have:

```
0 ? 3 : 4
```

So, you should actually be getting 4 as the result.