# C Programming - #define function

Tags: c

I am learning C in depth. But I am not getting this program. Somebody, please tell me how the output of the below program is **m=2, n=3**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX(a,b) a>b ? a:b
int main()
{
    int m,n;
    m=3+MAX(2,3);
    n=2*MAX(3,2);
    printf("m=%d, n=%d\n",m,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Learn about operator precedence.

Comment: Expand the macro by hand and look at a table of operator precedence and you will soon see the problem.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437404/min-and-max-in-c for the proper way of implementing a MAX macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what happens in your case:

```
int main() {
    int m,n;
    m=3+2>3 ? 2:3; //(3+2)>3 ? 2 : 3 = 2
    n=2*3>2 ? 3:2; //(2*3)>2 ? 3 : 2 = 3
    printf("m=%d, n=%d\n",m,n);
    return 0;
}
```

If you rewrite your defined to `#define MAX(a,b) ((a)>(b) ? (a):(b))`

then you will have desired output as it will be evaluated to:

```
//Correct way with parenthesis
int main() {
    int m,n;
    m=3+((2)>(3) ? (2):(3)); //6
    n=2*((3)>(2) ? (3):(2)); //6
    printf("m=%d, n=%d\n",m,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is why parenthesis in macro definitions are important.

A macro does simple text substitution.  So when you do this:

```
m=3+MAX(2,3);
```

It expands to this:

```
m=3+2>3 ? 2:3
```

With the implicit parenthesis:

```
m = ((3+2)>3) ? 2:3
```

Which is probably not what you want.

You need to put parenthesis around the entire macro as well as around each argument wherever it is used:

```
#define MAX(a,b) ((a)>(b) ? (a) : (b))
```

This will then expand to:

```
m = 3 + ((2)>(3) ? (2):(3))
```

Also note that with a macro like this you open yourself up to side effects of one of the operands.  For example, if you did this:

```
int a=2, b=3;
m = MAX(a++,b);
```

You would get:

```
int a=2, b=3;
m = ((a++) > (b) ? (a++) : (b));
```

This invokes undefined behavior because it attempts to modify `a` more than once in an expression without a sequence point.