# Unable the find the error but the compiler gives the following message:

Tags: c++, syntax-error

The error message says:
In function`void LCSlength(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string, int, int)`

Error:

> expression cannot be used as a function
>            lookup[ i ][ j ] = max (lookup[i - 1] [ j ],lookup[ i ] [ j - 1 ]);

```
#define max 20

int lookup[max][max];

void LCSlength(string x,string y,int m,int n)
{
  for(int i = 1;i<=m;i++)
  {
    for(int j = 1;j<=n;j++)
    {
      if(x[i - 1] == y[j - 1])
       lookup[i][j] = lookup[i - 1][j - 1] + 1;
       else
        lookup[i][j] = max(lookup[i - 1][j], lookup[i][j - 1]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if you have a function max which you havent shown for brevity, then you erase reference to it by "#define max 20" and the max function you may have declared elsewhere cant be accessed. Because once the preprocessor directive runs, the last line looks to the compiler like "lookup [i] [j] =  20(lookup[i-1][j] , lookup[i][j-1]);" You cant have a function called "20". Use an alternative label for "max" in the #define / array sizes, or create or rename the max function to something else

Comment: What do you want `max` to be? A placeholder for `20` or the name of the function (or macro) which returns the maximum value between two values? You could use `MAX_SIZE` for the former, while the latter is `std::max`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::max(lookup[i - 1][j], lookup[i][j - 1]);` and replace your macro name by something else, say `maximum`:

```cpp
#define maximum 20
int lookup[maximum][maximum];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the max function or use macro like this

```
#define MAX(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

refer to [MIN and MAX in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437404/min-and-max-in-c)

Edit 
Preprocessors are case sensitive and it is advised to keep them in capital letters. Just for the sake of correct answer, I am putting them in small caps. You can use a function as well.

```
#define max(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

if you can use C++11 use

```
constexpr int max = 20;
```

or if you can't use C++11 use

```
const int max = 20;
```

And don't skip the namespace to avoid ambiguities:

```
lookup[i][j] = std::max(lookup[i - 1][j], lookup[i][j - 1]);
```

### Explanation

You have a macro

```
#define max 20
```

Now the preprocessor is a quite stupid text-replacement tool, that will now replace *every* instance of "max" with "20". So you end up with

```
lookup[i][j] = 20(lookup[i - 1][j], lookup[i][j - 1]);
```

Which doesn't make any sense. Prime example why you shouldn't use macros in modern C++ ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you want to use the "max" function of stl, but you declared a variable called max at the beginning.
You should call std::max instead or change the name of your max variable.
In general, avoid using std to avoid those mistakes