# How to handle buffer size for unknown data sizes in network operations (socks proxy)?

Tags: c, networking, socks, forwarding

I am writing a socks4 proxy in C and everything works well, like I tested the data forwarding with a simple echo server as the remote peer.

But now I am not sure how to handle the data if the other protocols are used as they have different package sizes.

How do I know if the transmission is complete or how do I have to handle that everything is transmitted properly to the remote peer and vice versa to the client?

Here is my thread connection handler function:

```
// Contains the client socket and remote peer socket after successful connect:
typedef struct socks_connection {
    int client_sock;
    int target_sock;
} socks_connection;


void *socks_connection_thread(void *sockets) {
    printf("Thread started\n");
    socks_connection conn = *(socks_connection*) sockets;

    uint8_t buf[512];
    int rbytes;
    int wbytes;

    for(;;) {

        rbytes = recv(conn.client_sock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
        printf("read: %d\n", rbytes);
        if(rbytes < 0) {
            perror("read");
        }

        wbytes = send(conn.target_sock, buf, rbytes, 0);
        printf("send: %d\n", wbytes);
        if(rbytes < 0) {
            perror("send");
        }

        rbytes = recv(conn.target_sock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
        if(rbytes < 0) {
            perror("read");
        }
        printf("read: %d\n", rbytes);

        wbytes = send(conn.client_sock, buf, rbytes, 0);
        printf("send: %d\n", wbytes);
        if(rbytes < 0) {
            perror("send");
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT: I am trying to use `poll()` instead of `select()` and I want to know if it is normal for `poll` to use less code and additional work like i.e. `FD_SET, FD_ISSET` etc.

```
#define MAX_SOCKETS 2
#define DEFAULT_TIMEOUT (3 * 60 * 1000)
#define CLIENT_POLL 0
#define REMOTE_POLL 1

void *socks_connection_thread(void *pipefd) {

    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    socks_connection *conn = pipefd;
    int rc = 0;
    int timeout = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;

    struct pollfd pfds[MAX_SOCKETS];
    nfds_t nfds = MAX_SOCKETS;

    uint8_t client_buf[1024];
    size_t client_buf_size = 0;

    uint8_t target_buf[1024];
    size_t target_buf_size = 0;
    
    ssize_t num_bytes;

    memset(&pfds, 0, sizeof(pfds));

    

    int opt = 1;
    ioctl(conn->client_sock, FIONBIO, &opt);
    ioctl(conn->target_sock, FIONBIO, &opt);

    pfds[CLIENT_POLL].fd = conn->client_sock;
    pfds[CLIENT_POLL].events = POLLIN;

    pfds[REMOTE_POLL].fd = conn->target_sock;
    pfds[REMOTE_POLL].events = POLLIN;

    for(;;) {

        if(socksshutdown) break;

        /* waiting for some events */
        rc = poll(pfds, MAX_SOCKETS, timeout);
        if(rc < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "poll() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            break;
        }

        if(rc == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "poll() timed out. End Connection\n");
            break;
        }

        /* there is something to read form the client side */
        if(pfds[CLIENT_POLL].revents & POLLIN)
        {

            num_bytes = readFromSocket(conn->client_sock, client_buf, sizeof(client_buf));
            if(num_bytes < 0) break; // client connection lost
            if(num_bytes > 0) {
                printf("read from client: %s (%ld)\n", client_buf, num_bytes);
                client_buf_size += num_bytes;
            }
            num_bytes = sendToSocket(conn->target_sock, client_buf, num_bytes);
            if(num_bytes < 0) break;
            if(num_bytes > 0) {
                printf("forward to remote peer: %s (%ld)\n", client_buf, num_bytes);
            }
            pfds[CLIENT_POLL].revents = 0;

        }
        /* there is something to read from the remote side */
        else if(pfds[REMOTE_POLL].revents & POLLIN)
        {
            //printf("Got data from remote.\n");
            num_bytes = readFromSocket(conn->target_sock, target_buf, sizeof(target_buf));
            if (num_bytes < 0) break; // remote connection lost
            if (num_bytes > 0) {
                printf("read from client: %s (%ld)\n", target_buf, num_bytes);
                target_buf_size += num_bytes;
            }
            num_bytes = sendToSocket(conn->client_sock, target_buf, target_buf_size);
                if (num_bytes < 0) break;
                if (num_bytes > 0) {
                    printf("forward to client: %s (%ld)\n", target_buf, num_bytes);
                    // remove the sent bytes...
                } 
            pfds[REMOTE_POLL].revents = 0;
        } else {
            // unexpected event result appeared so close the connection
            break;
        }

    }

    // all done
    close(conn->client_sock);
    close(conn->target_sock);
    printf("Thread terminating\n");

}
```

Comment: tcp is a streaming protocol, so there's no way to know when a transmission ends until the socket is closed. Incidentally, why do you test `rBytes` after `send()`?

Comment: Is there any concern about it? Because `send` returns the number of bytes send or an error if any. This is not the release code, I will improve the handling of error etc. if I have an solution for the proper handling of the full request from the client.

Comment: Right, `send()` returns the number of bytes sent, which you assign to `wbytes`, so why are you testing against `rbytes`, which doesn't change, after `send()`?

Comment: Uff, absolutely my fault. I was copy pasting the `if cause`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOCKS is a straight passthrough proxy.  It has no concept of the protocols that pass through its tunnel.  Once the tunnel is established, its job is just to forward whatever bytes it receives.

TCP is a bidirectional byte stream, it has no concept of messages/packages, either party can send data at any time, or nothing at all.

There is no guarantee that the parties will send data in a coordinated manner as you have coded for. You won't know how much data will be sent, or which party is going to send data.  Maybe the target will initiate communications first. Or maybe the communication might not even be bi-directional at all.  Who knows.

So, your logic to `recv()` from the client first, then `send()` to the target, then `recv()` from the target, then `send()` to the client will simply not work.

You need to multiplex your socket operations, such as with `select()` or `epoll()`, or use asynchronous I/O, or use a dedicated thread per connection.  Either way, you can `recv()` from EITHER connection at ANY time, `send()`'ing along whatever you do happen to receive.

For example:

```
ssize_t readFromSocket(int sock, void *buf, size_t size) {
    char *pbuf = (char*) buf;
    ssize_t num_bytes, total = 0;

    while (total < size) {
        num_bytes = recv(sock, &pbuf[total], size-total, 0);
        if (num_bytes <= 0) {
            if ((num_bytes < 0) && ((errno == EAGAIN) || (errno == EWOULDBLOCK))) {
                break;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        total += num_bytes;
    }

    return total;
}

ssize_t sendToSocket(int sock, void *buf, size_t size) {
    char *pbuf = (char*) buf;
    ssize_t num_bytes, ssize_t total = 0;

    while (total < size) {
        num_bytes = send(sock, &pbuf[total], size-total, 0);
        if (num_bytes < 0) {
            if ((errno == EAGAIN) || (errno == EWOULDBLOCK)) {
                break;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        total += num_bytes;
    }

    return total;
}

void* socks_connection_thread(void* sockets) {
    printf("Thread started\n");
    socks_connection conn = *(socks_connection*) sockets;

    uint8_t client_buf[512];
    int client_buf_size = 0;

    uint8_t target_buf[512];
    int target_buf_size = 0;

    fd_set rfd, wfd, *prfd, *pwfd;
    int res, maxfd;

    if (conn.client_sock > conn.target_sock)
        maxfd = conn.client_sock;
    else
        maxfd = conn.target_sock;
    ++maxfd;

    // set the sockets to non-blocking mode...
    int opt = 1;
    ioctl(conn.client_sock, FIONBIO, &opt);
    ioctl(conn.target_sock, FIONBIO, &opt);

    while (true) {

        FD_ZERO(&rfd);
        FD_ZERO(&wfd);
        prfd = pwfd = NULL;

        // if the client has buffer space, check for more data...
        if (client_buf_size < sizeof(client_buf)) {
            prfd = &rfd;
            FD_SET(conn.client_sock, prfd);
        }

        // if the target has buffer space, check for more data...
        if (target_buf_size < sizeof(target_buf)) {
            prfd = &rfd;
            FD_SET(conn.target_sock, prfd);
        }

        // if the client has buffered data, check if the target is writable...
        if (client_buf_size > 0) {
            pwfd = &wfd;
            FD_SET(conn.target_sock, pwfd);
        }

        // if the target has buffered data, check if the client is writable...
        if (target_buf_size > 0) {
            pwfd = &wfd;
            FD_SET(conn.client_sock, pwfd);
        }

        // wait for one of the above conditions to be true...
        res = select(maxfd, prfd, pwfd, NULL, NULL);
        if (res < 0) {
            perror("select");
            break;
        }

        // does the client have new data?
        if (FD_ISSET(conn.client_sock, &rfd)) {
            // consume as many bytes as possible...
            num_bytes = readFromSocket(conn.client_sock, &client_buf[client_buf_size], sizeof(client_buf)-client_buf_size);
            if (num_bytes < 0) break;
            if (num_bytes > 0) {
                printf("read from client: %d\n", num_bytes);
                client_buf_size += num_bytes;
                // signal pending data for the target...
                FD_SET(conn.target_sock, &wfd);
            }
        }

        // does the target have new data?
        if (FD_ISSET(conn.target_sock, &rfd)) {
            // consume as many bytes as possible...
            num_bytes = readFromSocket(conn.target_sock, &target_buf[target_buf_size], sizeof(target_buf)-target_buf_size);
            if (num_bytes < 0) break;
            if (num_bytes > 0) {
                printf("read from target: %d\n", num_bytes);
                target_buf_size += num_bytes;
                // signal pending data for the client...
                FD_SET(conn.client_sock, &wfd);
            }
        }

        // send pending data to the client?
        if (FD_ISSET(conn.client_sock, &wfd)) {
            // send as many bytes as possible...
            num_bytes = sendToSocket(conn.client_sock, target_buf, target_buf_size);
            if (num_bytes < 0) break;
            if (num_bytes > 0) {
                printf("send to client: %d\n", num_bytes);
                // remove the sent bytes...
                target_buf_size -= num_bytes;
                memmove(target_buf, &target_buf[num_bytes], target_buf_size);
            }
        }

        // send pending data to the target?
        if (FD_ISSET(conn.target_sock, &wfd)) {
            // send as many bytes as possible...
            num_bytes = sendToSocket(conn.target_sock, client_buf, client_buf_size);
            if (num_bytes < 0) break;
            if (num_bytes > 0) {
                printf("send to target: %d\n", num_bytes);
                // remove the sent bytes...
                client_buf_size -= num_bytes;
                memmove(client_buf, &client_buf[num_bytes], client_buf_size);
            }
        }
    }

    // all done
    close(conn.client_sock);
    close(conn.target_sock);

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: I am testing your implementation right now, but I could not find anything to the max function. Can you tell me about the max function? Could not find anything about it.

Comment: @mortytheshorty [MIN and MAX in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437404/), but I have now updated my example to just remove `max()`

Comment: By setting the sockets to non-blocking your `sendToSocket` and `readFromSocket` functions are the blocking mechanism right? Why is that? And what if there is data send that's smaller than the buffer size. I was wondering why the client was blocking if I gave it a buffer that is bigger than the expected data.

Comment: I tried to implement a new thread function by using `poll()` instead of select as I read select should be avoided. Isn't it enought to `poll` on both sockets and as an event occurs on one I read from it as much as I can into the buffer and then send it to the opposite socket and vise versa? I will add my code to the question.

Comment: @mortytheshorty I set the sockets to non-blocking so that blocking reads/sends cannot occur, allowing the code to move on when needed. The only blocking in my example is on the select() itself when there is no work to be done at all. Otherwise, when a socket has data to read, the code will read until either the buffer fills up or there is no more data to read. And when a socket has buffered data to send, the code will send until the buffer is empty or the peer stops accepting data.

Comment: @mortytheshorty As for `poll()`, you don't need a separate thread for that. Yes, you can use `poll()` similarly to how I use `select()` in my example.  I simply chose not to group the reads and sends together for each transaction, like you have.  It may take several loop iterations to send a buffer completely, which your code does not take into account, but my code does. When a receiver stops accepting data (ie, its receive buffer is full), you have to wait for that socket to enter a writable state (ie, its buffer has cleared up space) before you can continue sending data to it again.