# Using conditional operator find a smallest number among two numbers

Tags: c, conditional-operator

Kindly give an detailed explanation too.
How does it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional operator `? :` works in a similar manner to `if else`.

So:

```
int A;
int B;
// some code that sets the values of A and B
return A>B?B:A
```

Is the same as

```
int A;
int B; 
    // some code that sets the values of A and B   
if A>B
    return B;
else
    return A;
```

An explanation of the conditional operator:

```
`<Perform operation that gives a boolean result>` ? <return this answer if true> : <return this answer if false>
```

So you could have:

```
int smallestValue;
int inputA;
int inputB;

//some code that sets the value of inputA and inputB - perhaps from console input

smallestValue = (inputA < inputB) ? inputA : inputB;
```

Comment: Can i get examples with numbers instead ?
Like how to find the smallest numberr among two numbers please.

Answer (score 3):

```
return a<b ? a : b
```

is equivalent to

```
if (a<b)
    return a;
else
    return b;
```

Comment: +1 - beat me too it. Slow update times today.

Comment: Can i get examples with numbers instead ?
Like how to find the smallest number among two numbers please.

Comment: I don't understand. `a` and `b` can be whatever you want. They can be numbers. If you mean how do you use conditional operator to find the minimum of literals like `6` and `9` say then that's pointless. You can do it by inspection. Also, if you have specific questions to ask, don't add them in comments, instead edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's a macro does the same work...

```
#define min(a, b) a<b ? a : b
```

Comment: That's a potentially very bad macro. Multiple evaluations of a and b.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I don't know why did you say that, but you can have a look to the 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458723/c-macro-for-minimum-of-two-numbers)

Comment: Well that link pretty much covers the issues